# Is there a way to run a while x amount of times at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a while loop where something has 99 hp, i want it to randomly "hit" it till its 0, now i want to do this lets say a million times to check on differences. Is there a way to do multiple of these "simulations" at the same time? Kind of like how in machine learning a teacher teaches multiple students at the same time.

Right now i just add a for statement so i iterate this while loop a million times. But this can take a while.

For example:

```py
import random

hp = 99
for n in range(1000000):
    while hp > 0:
        hp -=  random.randint(0,10)
```

I'd like it to have to iterate that while loop alot less times or just once if possible unless for some reason this actually takes longer than the above code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should learn about threading or multi-processing, but that's a subject for a whole tutorial and can't be fit for an answer here

Comment: Hmm okay i'll have a look around. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: If you are new at multiprocessing/multithreading, you might want to look at https://github.com/ray-project/ray

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiprocessing to run the function simultaneously n amount of times.

Here is an example where it runs your function n times on 4 cores, and prints the average amount of 'ticks' required to deplete the health to 0.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import random

def depleteHp(input):
    hp = 99
    ticks = 0
    while hp > 0:
        ticks += 1
        hp -=  random.randint(0,10)
    return ticks

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    n = 1000
    inputs = range(n)
    # calc depleteHp output using 4 processes
    out_list = pool.map(depleteHp, inputs)
    # average  
    print (sum(out_list) / float(n))
```

pool.map(function, list_of_inputs) 'maps' the function over n processors feeding the next item of the 'list_of_inputs' each time. As such in this case it feeds the numbers 0 to 1000 to the depleteHp function.

out_list then stores a list of the returned value each time.

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful to learn. Is there any reason when i put a print in the function sometimes in the output it prints out the ticks on the same line with a blank space after it? Or is this maybe just because of the IDE im using (pycharm)

Example:
`181

2
1019
3
20`